# Vaadin SEO how?

Tags: java, gwt, seo, search-engine, vaadin

I am going to use Vaadin UI framework to develop web application where indexing in search engines is very critical. And I know that the most search engines not indexing GWT sites.

I have already googled and found some solutions that identifies search engines by user agent and redirect them for special indexable pages.

I think it is not best way.

Is there any creative ideas?
(That really will amaze!!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find some useful discussion [here](http://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/message/95599#_19_message_95599).

Answer (score 3):

First of all I think that Vaadin is not good choice for web site development, because of its performance problems(inefficient traffic using). Generally Vaadin was created for making closed intranet web applications(not sites). Therefore I think the best solution would be looking for another tools. Or if you want to implement some complex service in your web site, it would be better to use Vaadin for implementing that parts only, not all site.

Nevertheless it is possible to mix of regular way of web site development(with static content such as html and css files, which are optimized for Search robots) and Vaadin/GWT way for implementing complicated web logic by including Vaadin's parts directly in prepared static html files.